# Storing Function app setting as Key Vault references vs as straight values?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-keyvault

I'm developing a function app that connects to AWS SDK via access key and secret key.
Right now I'm storing them in the Application Settings as straight values.

Is there any sense for me to store them in Key Vault and put the references to them in Application Settings?

On Azure website its says about Application Settings that "**These settings are stored encrypted"**, so will it be much more secure to store them in Key Vault?

Is it a security concern to store access keys as straight values in Application Settings?

Comment: Storing API access keys in App settings is done often and it is _not insecure_. However, if there is a need for higher security or need to comply to some security standards, then you can store in Key Vault.

Comment: If several azure function apps are needing that API access keys, then it makes more sense to store it as a secret in Key Vault, so that future changes to that is done in one central place.

Comment: From Azure [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-security), "App settings and connection strings are stored encrypted in Azure, and they're decrypted only before being injected into your app's process memory when the app starts. The encryption keys are rotated regularly."

Comment: Using of a Key Vault make sense if administrator of the Function App should never see the secret value: you can give access to the Key Vault for Function App identity (system or user manager) and give to the Function App's admin only the reference to this KV secret. If KV admin, Function app admin and developer are the same persons then no real reason to use KV.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**,

**You can store the Confidential Settings like Access Keys, Connection Settings in 3 Places in the Azure Functions Cloud Development**.

They are:

1. Azure Functions > Configuration Blade > Application Settings
2. Azure Key Vault
3. Azure App Configuration

Yes! The stored settings in both Configuration Blade and Key Vault are ***encrypted*** which means encrypted when the app is idle and ***decrypted*** when the app starts. Also, encryption and decryption keys changes regularly which prevents from Security threats.

---

**Azure Key Vault**:

Assume you have stored the Service Bus connection string in the Key Vault. That you want to retrieve in the Function App through Application Settings but here in the app setting you can define as:

```
"connection": @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS/)
```

This KeyVault URI cannot be accessed by any other user until they are assigned with ***System*** or ***User Assigned Managed Identity*** Permission.

---

**Azure App Configuration**:

**To manage application settings centrally, another best service is Azure App Configuration which complements Azure Key Vault**.

You can store the Application Settings, Access Keys, Confidential Certificate Passwords in App Configuration Store and can retrieve using client library provided by Microsoft to your application. For Connecting methods to your application for different languages/frameworks, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview#use-app-configuration) and to use Azure App Configuration in Azure Functions, visit this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process).